# stretching border to edge of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to stretch the borders of list elements **all the way to the edge of the screen**. Bellow is a picture of the project, the lists are in the yellow navigation bar. I am only allowed to use HTML, CSS and bootstrap. I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.[project]

```css
#header-nav {
  background-color: #DEB887;

}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 0rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-family: cursive;
    }
  h4 {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    padding-bottom: 4vw;
  }
  h5 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #Chicken-tile {
    background-color: #8FBC8F;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5vw;
  }
  #Beef-tile {
    background-color: lightpink;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5vw;
  }
  #Sushi-tile {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5vw;   
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Module 3 Solution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
<body>
    <header>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold" c href="#">Food, LCC</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none d-md-none d-sm-none border-dark mb-1 mt-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item  d-lg-none d-md-none text-center fw-bold border border-dark">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Chicken</a>
        <li class="nav-item d-lg-none d-md-none text-center fw-bold border border-top-0 border border-dark">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Beef</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-lg-none d-lg-md-none text-center fw-bold border-top-0 border border-dark">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sushi</a>
        </li>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</nav>
</header> 
</div>
      <h4>Our Menu</h4>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="home-tiles" class="row g-1">
            <div id="Chicken-tile">
            <h5>Chicken </h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ducimus maxime laudantium fugiat autem at in distinctio laborum, corrupti delectus eius ipsum mollitia, perferendis sit doloribus voluptate nesciunt, commodi praesentium dolorum eveniet error. Accusantium consequatur quos possimus repellat autem quas aspernatur atque, incidunt soluta dolor id suscipit modi maxime esse, voluptatum dignissimos dolores tempore voluptatem consectetur iure, necessitatibus unde reiciendis praesentium! Voluptatem reprehenderit illum ipsum rem, eveniet excepturi quo et placeat voluptate magnam molestiae iste facere sapiente ipsa, deleniti eos ad, velit atque corrupti delectus molestias est! Iusto, explicabo? 
            </p></div>
            <div id="Beef-tile">
            <h5>Beef</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ducimus maxime laudantium fugiat autem at in distinctio laborum, corrupti delectus eius ipsum mollitia, perferendis sit doloribus voluptate nesciunt, commodi praesentium dolorum eveniet error. Accusantium consequatur quos possimus repellat autem quas aspernatur atque, incidunt soluta dolor id suscipit modi maxime esse, voluptatum dignissimos dolores tempore voluptatem consectetur iure, necessitatibus unde reiciendis praesentium! Voluptatem reprehenderit illum ipsum rem, eveniet excepturi quo et placeat voluptate magnam molestiae iste facere sapiente ipsa, deleniti eos ad, velit atque corrupti delectus molestias est! Iusto, explicabo? 
            </p></div>
            <div id="Sushi-tile">
            <h5>Sushi</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ducimus maxime laudantium fugiat autem at in distinctio laborum, corrupti delectus eius ipsum mollitia, perferendis sit doloribus voluptate nesciunt, commodi praesentium dolorum eveniet error. Accusantium consequatur quos possimus repellat autem quas aspernatur atque, incidunt soluta dolor id suscipit modi maxime esse, voluptatum dignissimos dolores tempore voluptatem consectetur iure, necessitatibus unde reiciendis praesentium! Voluptatem reprehenderit illum ipsum rem, eveniet excepturi quo et placeat voluptate magnam molestiae iste facere sapiente ipsa, deleniti eos ad, velit atque corrupti delectus molestias est! Iusto, explicabo?
            </p></div>
        </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to stretch the borders of list elements **all the way to the edge of the screen**. Bellow is a picture of the project, the lists are in the yellow navigation bar. I am only allowed to use HTML, CSS and bootstrap. I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.[project]

Comment: You seemed to have forgotten to attach the screenshot. Also please include the code blocks you have and share what you've tried to do.

Comment: Just remove the padding?

Comment: And [mre] should be minimal.